# How to get horizontal HTML table in email body in python?

Tags: python, html, smtplib

I need to send sql table data in the email body as a html table in python. So I have used following method to fetch data first.

```
def table_row(date, X1, X2, X3):
    return f"""
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">{date}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{X1}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{X2}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{X3}</td>
```

"""

```
table_rows = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    table_rows.append(
        table_row(
            date=row['Date'],
            X1=row['X1'],
            X2=row['X2'],
            X3=row['X3'],
        )
    )

table_rows_str = "\n".join(table_rows)
```

Now I created the email body as follows,

```
import smtplib

sender = ''
receivers = ['']

message = f"""From: XX <XX@abc.lk>
To:  ; 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject :{mailsubject}

Dear All,<br/><br/> Please refer below data  :<br/><br/>

Data : <br/>
<table border="2" padding: 10px border: 1px solid black border-collapse: collapse cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>Date</b></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>X1</b></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>X2</b></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><b>X3</b></td>
        </tr>
        {table_rows_str}
    </table><br/><br/>
    

      
 

<b>This is an automated email, Please do not reply ...</b>
    
"""


try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('',25)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    pass
except smtplib.socket.error:
    pass
```

This works fine and I am getting the email as expected as follows,

[image]

But I need to make this table in a horizontal way, so I could easily identify some patterns. I want the output as follows,

[image]

What are the changes I need to add here to get the required output? I am beginner for this HTML contents.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using  attribute for table header's instead of td
to understand more the table go for https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp